# How to listen EditText changes when changes are made by Keyboard

Tags: android

<s>I have an `EditText` which accepts changes from keyboard or seekBar. How can I listen to changes from keyboard?</s>

I want know, when changing makes input from keyboard, when changing from seekBar

Comment: Not clear ,please add more info.

Comment: use **yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher)** method, search for that method in google you will get many examples

Comment: I want know, when changing makes input from keyboard, when changing from seekBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
  int arg3) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
  @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(...){
     /// update the seekBar HERE
   }
}};
```

Comment: I want know, when changing makes input from keyboard, when changing from seekBar

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) to your EditText. Here is a tutorial showing how to use it:

http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-11-using-textwatcher-in-android/

Comment: I want know, when changing makes input from keyboard, when changing from seekBar